# When using pivots to create confidence intervals, it seems that pivots are always depending on θ?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, confidence-interval

I am really confused on how to find a pivot, it seems that it's just always derived randomly and on top of that even though it's defined that a pivot should nto depend on θ the pivot function always has θ in it? Doesn't that mean it depends on θ?
Like, for this example below:
[Example Pivot Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgaww.png)

It says in the solution that U = Y/θ doesn't depend on θ so it can be used as a pivot. What?? How did we arrive at U = Y/θ in the first place, was it just be guessing? And if U has θ in its function then doesn't that precisely mean that it does depend on θ? I'm very confused

Comment: In that particular case, $\theta$ would be a scale parameter for the distribution of $Y$ so if you divide $Y$ by $\theta$ then $U=Y/\theta$ has an exponential distribution with mean $1$.  You know the distribution of $U$ (it does not depend on $\theta$) so you can find an interval which $U$ would have a $90\%$ of being in, let's say $[c_1,c_2]$, giving you a couple of inequalities which you can rearrange to give a $90\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ given the observation $Y$

Comment: By definition, a pivotal quantity itself need not be free of the parameter; but its **distribution** must be free of the parameter.